# Does the following equation show transitive nature, symmetric and reflexive?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

> Does the following equation show transitive nature, symmetric and
>   reflexive?  $$d(a,b) = \lvert a-b \rvert \le 2 $$

I am really having trouble with this problem any help would be appreciated. I have tried to rearrange it but am not sure how to do it with the absolute value problem.

Comment: Please clean up your problem. Those are properties of the binary relation $d(.,.)$ and not of the inequality.

Comment: What does it mean to write $d(a,b)$? Does $d(0,1)$? What about $d(2,4)$? And $d(2,5)$? What does it mean for $d$ to be transitive? Symmetric? Reflexive?

Comment: Hint: For transitivity, try some examples. The meaning of the relation between $a, b$ is: the distance between $a$ and $b$ is at most $2$. So consider $0,2$ and $2, 4$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

This relation is reflexive if $d(a,a) \leq 2$ for all $a$. Which is true as $d(a,a) = 0$.

Symmetric: does $d(a,b) \leq 2$ imply $d(b,a) \leq 2$ for all $a, b$?

Transitive: does $d(a,b) \leq 2$ and $d(b,c) \leq 2$ imply $d(a,c) \leq 2$ for all $a,b,c$?